# imageview.setOnClickListener not works in childview

Tags: android

Just like the title,following is code,the image in childview can't work well,please help me find the reason,thanks.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    View parentView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.horizontal_scrollview, verticalScrollView, false);
    horizontalScrollview = (LinearLayout) parentView.findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollParentLayout);
    texthead = (TextView) parentView.findViewById(R.id.txthead);
    texthead.setText("Heading" + i);

    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
         View childView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.horizontal_scroll_child, verticalScrollView, false);
         childLayout = (LinearLayout) childView.findViewById(R.id.child_layout);
         image = (ImageView) childLayout.findViewById(R.id.image);
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.home);
         text = (TextView) childLayout.findViewById(R.id.text);
         text.setText("Detail" + j);
         horizontalScrollview.addView(childView);
     }

     verticalScrollView.addView(parentView);
 }

 image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Hi",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
      }
 });

//end image click event not work
```

Comment: where is setOnClickListner?

Comment: i am not include it. but after for loop its image.setonclicklister is there.

Comment: Please paste complete code here.

Comment: after loop this code will be there                                                        image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Hi",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 

                }
            });

Answer (score 0):

You should add image.setOnClickListener in loop,in your code,you add onclicklistener at last,but it only can add to last imageview you found.so please try this:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      View parentView =   getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.horizontal_scrollview, verticalScrollView, false);
      horizontalScrollview = (LinearLayout) parentView.findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollParentLayout);
      texthead = (TextView) parentView.findViewById(R.id.txthead);
      texthead.setText("Heading" + i);
      for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
         View childView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.horizontal_scroll_child, verticalScrollView, false);
         childLayout = (LinearLayout) childView.findViewById(R.id.child_layout);
         image = (ImageView) childLayout.findViewById(R.id.image);
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.home);
         image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Hi",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
             }
         });
         text = (TextView) childLayout.findViewById(R.id.text);
         text.setText("Detail" + j);
         horizontalScrollview.addView(childView);
     }

     verticalScrollView.addView(parentView);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks it work... Actually i was try that but use some other imageview... that why i am so confused